# Error when trying to mock chained methods in Angular Jasmine test

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I am trying to configure mocks for an activated route in one of my components. The piece of code I am trying to mock is

```
    this.idNumber = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('idNumber');
```

I am trying to use this to mock the chained method call, but am getting an exception when the 'get' method is called.

```
    activatedRoute = jasmine.createSpyObj('ActivatedRoute', ['snapshot', 'paramMap', 'get']);

    activatedRoute.snapshot.and.returnValue(activatedRoute);
    activatedRoute.paramMap.and.returnValue(activatedRoute);
    activatedRoute.get.and.returnValue(of("testId"));
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

Answer (score 0):

After debugging with some console log statements, I found that despite the error message, my issue was that I had yet to mock a call to a service lower in the ngInit. I am not sure why the error message mentioned an unrelated part of code